# How To Change The StartPage Of The Windows Phone 8 Application In C#

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5

I have a windows phone 8 application in Visual Studion 2012. Depending on a data model in memory I have to display a respective page. For e.g. if data.Number = 1, then I should display Page1.xaml, if data.Number = 18 then I should display Page2.xaml, etc.

That navigation has to happen when the application becomes live i.e. comes to foreground. How can I make the required changes in App.xaml.cs file to accommodate this mandate?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you seem to think it will possible to dynamic change the .cs file while the application is running this won't be possible ( I based this statement on your statement "...when the application becomes live" ) if you mean something else please clarify. Furthermore it would be interesting to know what you have tried. It should be easy enough to connect the value `1` to connect if a certain page should be shown or not.

Comment: I just found the solution. If you look at the code in the context of App.xaml.cs, we expect it should work.

(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/Counting.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

But the problem is that it keeps throwing exceptions.

Comment: **If causes an exception then its not a solution.** When you figure out the cause of the exception you should answer your own question.

Comment: I know it and it does not need a reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below implies the answer consider the fact that we need to call dispatcher's begin invoke:

["Navigation is not allowed when the task is not in the foreground" in WP7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373533/navigation-is-not-allowed-when-the-task-is-not-in-the-foreground-in-wp7-applic)